# Prevent default behavior in text input while pressing arrow up

Tags: javascript, events, input, keyboard, default

I’m working with basic HTML `<input type="text"/>` text field with a numeric value.

I’m adding JavaScript event `keyup` to see when user presses arrow up key (`e.which == 38`) – then I increment the numeric value.

The code works well, but there’s one thing that bugs me. Both Safari/Mac and Firefox/Mac move cursor at the very beginning when I’m pressing the arrow up key. This is a default behavior for every `<input type="text"/>` text field as far as I know and it makes sense.

But this creates not a very aesthetic effect of cursor jumping back and forward (after value was altered).

The jump at the beginning happens on `keydown` but even with this knowledge I’m not able to prevent it from occuring. I tried the following:

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Putting `e.preventDefault()` in `keyup` event doesn’t help either.

Is there any way to prevent cursor from moving?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To preserve cursor position, backup `input.selectionStart` before changing value.

The problem is that WebKit reacts to `keydown` and Opera prefers `keypress`, so there's kludge: both are handled and throttled.

```
var ignoreKey = false;
var handler = function(e)
{
    if (ignoreKey)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) 
    {
        var pos = this.selectionStart;
        this.value = (e.keyCode == 38?1:-1)+parseInt(this.value,10);        
        this.selectionStart = pos; this.selectionEnd = pos;

        ignoreKey = true; setTimeout(function(){ignoreKey=false},1);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

input.addEventListener('keydown',handler,false);
input.addEventListener('keypress',handler,false);
```

Comment: Busted it! Thanks a lot, it’s perfect. :)

Comment: Up vote for "kludge"!  Worked for me, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 19):

I found that a better solution is just to `return false;` to prevent the default arrow key behavior:

```
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowUp' || e.key === 'ArrowDown') return false;
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks man. The idea is to use the keydown event instead of keyup.

Comment: Right - keydown is the trick. Note that returning false seems to stop the event's propagation entirely, whereas `preventDefault()` will let the input box ignore the event, while still allowing other listeners to handle it as it bubbles up.

Comment: @Lukas , your solution worked best for me. However, I'm calling `e.preventDefault();` instead of returning `false`. The latter didn't achieve the freezing of the up-arrow key behavior. Thanks for posting an alternate, simpler solution.

Comment: This is the correct answer! I had to use the keydown event to stop the cursor moving and then the keyup event to get the input value when needed

Comment: Using e.code === 'ArrowUp' || e.code === 'ArrowDown' will make the code is much easier to read.

Comment: Perfect solution! Saved me so much time, I'm using Vue and all I had to do is `<input @keydown.up.down.prevent />`.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there is a better and simpler method to do this job.

```
$('input').bind('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == '38' || e.keyCode == '40'){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Yes, it is so easy!

Answer (score 2):

In my case (react) helped:

```js
onKeyDown = {
  (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowUp' || e.key === 'ArrowDown') e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

and `onKeyUp` was fully functional

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code and it seems that it cancels the event but if you don't press the arrow for very short time - it fires keypress event and that event actually moves cursor. Just use preventDefault() also in keypress event handler and it should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, `e.preventDefault()` in `keypress` event prevents me from entering anything there (I want inputs to work like in Firebug). And it doesn’t solve my problem, at least in my browser – cursor still jumps at the very beginning.

Answer (score -2):

Probably not. You should instead seek for a solution to move the cursor back to the end of the field where it was. The effect would be the same for the user since it is too quick to be perceived by a human.

I googled some and found this piece of code. I can't test it now and it is said to not to work on IE 6.

textBox.setSelectionRange(textBox.value.length, textBox.value.length);

Comment: Thanks. Actually updating input.value will result in cursor moving back at the end. So I might detect cursor’s position and then restore it after change is made (if it’s in the middle of number, for example).

But I’m still looking for better solution, if it’s available.