# jquery keypress replace character or string from json

Tags: jquery, replace, keypress

Global Json object which is initialized through ajax post call to php and it returns values
like following(

```
$arr = array('h' => 'html', 'l' => 'li', 'p' => 'pre', 'd' =>'dom', 'e' => 'element'); 
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I can get the value of json object in jQuery.

There is a textbox to which ketpress event is mapped. Is it possible where user type the letter ***h*** in textbox instead of h it should replaced with value **json_obj['h']** that is ***html***. Where json_obj is variable which hold the json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of questions in here: [final example](http://jsfiddle.net/43dPx/1/)

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the php array: `echo json_encode($arr);`

[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
 var lookUpObject;
 $.getJSON({
     'something.php',
      success: function (data) {
         lookUpObject = data;
      }
 });
```

then [**keypress**](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

var lookUpObject = {
    h: 'html',
    p: 'php'
};

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').keypress(function (event) {
        var result = lookUpObject [String.fromCharCode(event.which)];

        if (result) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(val + result);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will capture keyup events and use the key pressed to replace the textbox's text with what is in your array. Notice though I did not put in any validation or error checking (such as if key pressed exists in array) which you should probably do.

```
$('#inputID').keyup(function(e) {
  var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  $(this).val($arr[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check, does item user pressd is [in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array). If so, then [prevent default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080532/prevent-default-behavior-in-text-input-while-pressing-arrow-up) action and put that value.